# Append java object to another using jackson databind annotation

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I need to send json data to a post call in java. The following is the code

my pojo class

```
public class Data{

    @JSONProperty("clientIP")
    String clientIP;

    @JSONProperty("empID")
    String empID;

    public Data setClientIP(String clientIp){
        this.clientIP = clientIp;
        return this;
    }

    public Data setEmpID(String empId){
        this.empID = empId;
        return this;
    }

    public String toString(){ /*toString conversion*/ }
}
```

Filter class where am setting clientIp

```
public doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response){
     HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
     String clientIP = httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr();
     Data data = new Data();
     data.setClientIP(clientIP);
}
```

Java class where am setting other emp related data for example userId

```
public Emp createEmp(empId, /*other emp related data*/){

   Data data = new Data();
   data.setEmpID(empId); 

   //append clientIp to this data object

   ConvertToJSON(data);
}
```

in another service class am converting this data to json formatted string using jackson binding. Here I want to append previously set clientIp to this data so that I can convert entire data object to json formatted string

Class where am converting java object to json

```
convertToJSON(Object data){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = null;
    jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(data);
}

I need output like { clientIP: 123.123.123.123, empID: emp123 }     
currently it displays { clientIP: null, empID: emp123} which is obvious
```

Comment: Because for method `doFilter` you create an instance of `Data` to set `clientIP` and for method `createEmp` you create another instance of `Data` to set `empId`.

Comment: @LHCHIN I know that, that's why it is showing null. My question is, is there any other way I can append clientIp to new isntance?

Comment: Where do you call `createEmp` method?

Comment: @Iris_geek One way is to store the `clientIP` info. into session, then retrieve it from session while you calling method `createEmp` and set it.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment, one simple way is to store `clienIP` into session attribute in your web filter as follows:

```
String clientIP = httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr();
HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
session.setAttribute("X-CLIENT-IP", clientIP);
```

Then you can use `request.getSession().getAttribute("X-CLIENT-IP").toString()` to retrieve client IP if you have a declaration of `HttpServletRequest request`.
After that, you can pass it as an argument for mehtod `createEmp` such as

```
public Emp createEmp(empId, clientIp) {
    Data data = new Data();
    data.setClientIP(clientIp);
    data.setEmpID(empId);
    ...
}
```